# Chrome extension, Download a blob file. This is not done correctly on all sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, blob, content-security-policy

i currently develop a chrome extension. This extension create a blob and let the user download the "file" blob.

My problem is when i create the file, it's on some site it's open correctly, and other website it's open in a new tab

There is my code, i think i did not make mistake

```
function downloadBlob(blob){
var FileName = "test.txt";
 var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var Link = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob, { type: "application/octet-stream" });
       var a = window.document.createElement("a");
          a.href = Link;
          a.download = FileName;
          document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Did the CSP of the website, could impact my blob download ?

I also try to return the link, set it to a new link. Always the same result. When i return the link, if i "right click" and press save as, my file is save successfully.

I also see there is a `chrome.downloads.dowload` can i use it in my extension ? I try it, but did not work.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Comment: chrome.downloads can't be used in a content script, you should use it in your popup/background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm i try in my Background.js script, and it did't work.

Comment: Then you need to show us MCVE :-) Also make sure you're looking at the [correct console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029).